# CUDA PTX, driver api - how to get global variable from kernel after execution

Tags: c++, c, cuda, ptx

Here's part of  kernel code - declaring variables and desired operation for each thread

```
.global.f32 sum = 0.0
.reg.f32 reg;
atom.global.add.f32 reg, [sum], val;
```

I want to add different variable in each thread to a global variable sum.
I assume that code posted above is correct - everything compiles smoothly. But I have problem with getting value of global variable sum back to the host.

I've got following code for host, after kernel execution.

```
CUdeviceptr hostSumPtr;
size_t bytes;
cuModuleGetGlobal(&hostSumPtr, &bytes, hModule, "sum");
```

but that returns error code 500 "CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND"

Is there any way to get value of global variable declared in kernel to the host, or any way to bypass this problem by different approach?

Comment: What scope have you declared `sum` at in the PTX? Is it inside the kernel, or at compilation unit scope. I think only the latter is supported.

Comment: I declared it right after starting { bracket. - sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Obviously you declared it in the PTX. But I am asking *where* in the PTX? Within the kernel declaration our outside it?

Comment: I declared it right after starting { bracket. Should I declare it before kernel function declaration?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It would be sooo much easier if you have posted more complete code someone could analyze. Playing guessing games in comments isn't much fun

Comment: Here's a full kernel code: http://pastebin.com/VTnFh2hT
When I declared .global .f32 before KERN function - kernel compiles, but cuModuleLoad returned 300

Comment: Okay, i fixed this problem after hours of research - I declared variable before main kernel function - as you mentioned, changed version to 3.0 and architecture to sm_30.
Thank you very much!

Comment: please add a short answer to this question detailing what you did to solve the problem, for the next person that comes along within a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 problems:

1. Global variable should be declared outside of kernel scope.
2. Architecture must be set to sm_30 and above (this only applies for this particular case and details not shown)
3. Kernel version must be set to 3.0 and above (this also only applies to this particular case and details not shown in the question)

Problem fixed.

Comment: I have edited this to note that the last two were implementation details specific to your GPU and build setup. They are not related to the PTX global symbol accessibility from the driver or runtime API